# html change/replace string after input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
function convertUnits(obj) {
  if($(obj).is(":checked")){
    $(obj).after(' "');
  }else{
    $(obj).after(' mm');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' id='units' onchange="convertUnits(this)"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to change/replace text after a text input depending on which radio button is chosen.

I can add text but it doesn't replace it...

I'm using this code to add the text... `convInputs` is an array of all the inputs I want to add text to the end of the input. Depending on the checkbox selected it's either ' /', ' "' or ' mm' like in the example text.

Right now when I switch checkbox the text is just added together and not replaced with the new text... ie: / " mm.

[https://jsfiddle.net/frankn/c6mjvLxd/19/][1]

edit: added jsfiddle with a simplified code example of my actual code and what's happening.

edit #2: as suggested I added code snippet here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that includes the HTML and JavaScript that shows the problem occurring. The current code will simply add a space and `mm`  after the text of each element in `convInputs` (and could be shortened to `convInputs.after(' mm');`). You can use Stack Snippets to provide a runnable snippet here on Stack Overflow; use the button in the editor toolbar that has `<>` in it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey sorry about the messy question and lack of information... kinda rushed it. I added a jsfiddle. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Your [mcve] need to be here, in your question, not on a third party site. SO can reproduce the same executable JavaScript snippets that jsFiddle can, so there's no need to use them for this

Comment: Yeah, no, a jsfiddle ain't gonna cut it. I recommended Stack Snippets because the code has to exist on Stack Overflow, not just on an external site.

Comment: Never used Stack Snippets... but I'll give it a try...

Comment: There you go... learn something new everyday... thanks again for the feedback and suggestions.

Comment: Okay, so `after` just appends to whatever's there now, not to what was there originally. You need to track what was there originally, and append to that. I'd reset the original value before calling `after`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ... Ah ok, makes sense. Any idea how I could reset the original value?

Comment: I would suggest using another element, like a `label`, to hold more information about what the radio button is for, then append the text to that. Then, on document ready, you can just grab what's in the `label` and keep it in a variable. Then, in your event handler, just set the `label`'s text to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a messy question and some help and suggections... here's what I came up with...

```js
function convertUnits(obj) {
  if($(obj).is(":checked")){
    $(obj).next().remove()
    $(obj).after("<label> test</label>")
  }else{
    $(obj).next().remove()
    $(obj).after("<label> new</label>")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' id='units' onchange="convertUnits(this)"/>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```